# Put and Delete Not Work in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using Web-API v2 in my project.
Put and Delete work in iis8 but Put and Delete not work and not found error in iis10. please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Kindly refer to link for this problem in iis 10 https://betimdrenica.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/web-api-on-iis-8-0-405-method-not-allowed-for-put/.

I have almost stuck with this issue. now found this link is very useful. this problem is happened by enabling the "WebDev Publishing" option check while installing iis using windows feature "Turn Windows Features On or Off" in 
"Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features" section.

Answer (score 0):

some cases this http verbs ar no allowed, so you need to override it, please see the following article: HTTP PUT or DELETE not allowed? [Use X-HTTP-Method-Override for your REST Service with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx)